# Is it possible to display ComboBox items by categories?

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-8, categories

I am working on a software program which enables to send specific commands to an external machine. This software has a command editor which starts with a ComboBox listing every possible command tag. I have 62 command tags which are separated into 5 distinct categories and I would like to specify it to the user with 5 headers on the items list.

I know we can do it in C# using `ComboBox.GroupStyle`, but I can't find an equivalent in Java. Is there a solution for this? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: not supported in fx combo

Comment: @kleopatra maybe an alternative?

Comment: not that I know of. You could try a custom cell implementation: you would need some indication in your data/related data that a new grouping starts and let the cell for the first item in a group have a separator above it's content (or a border) never tried :)

Comment: I was thinking of that: maybe we can set v-boxes as items but selection will cause a problem. Another solution would be to add labels and custom separators (as you said) then unselect separator items, but there may be a more robust solution.

Comment: whatever you do, never-ever use nodes as data!

Comment: anyway, the question is getting off-topic for SO - please come back with concrete problem (as [mcve]) when you found a possible solution and are stuck :)

Comment: Yes I wanted to but I was given a short deadline for my work and I don't have time to produce the MRE for the moment.

Comment: Did you think of using a TreeView (maybe in a PopUp that is shown when the user clicks a button styled like (close to) a ComboBox) ?

Comment: @user7399085 No that seems good :) I'll try something like that

Comment: I'm afraid that only reasonable option is Button with Popup. I've tried to implement desired feature using ComboBox but it has too many flaws to be usable. Do not try to implement ListCell. Imo it has no chances to be a successful solution.

Comment: _Do not try to implement ListCell. Imo it has no chances to be a successful solution._ wondering why you think so? It's _the_ approach to visually configure cells and should be simple and straightforward ... if all the devils keep reasonably quiet <g>

Comment: @0009laH One more suggestion Use a TableView and populate it with the 5 distinct categories Clickon the category and go to either another TableView or a given Combo Box associated with the category

Comment: @Grendel Yes, @user7399085 has suggested the same thing :) It is something similar to a `Menu` component containing 5 `Menu` with some `MenuItem` elements. I'm using this solution because that seems to be the most simple and elegant way.

Answer (score -1):

[image]using javafx menuButton with grid

Comment: please outline _how_ you achieved it

Comment: GridPane, menuButton and CustomMenu. that's all. then drag Gridpane to customMenu.

Comment: use menuButton then remove menuItems from it. then put CustomMenu in it after that design your GridPane then drag it to CustomMenu. that's all